# Recycler view comes to initial item when the next page of items are loaded

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley, swiperefreshlayout, android-paging

I have done paging for my recyclerview to fetch items from api using volley, i have tried a solution which is already asked , but what i am facing is when a new items are loaded from next page means, page refresh and loads from a start, so can anyone help on how to load item continuously without loading from a start.. Your suggestion and answeres will be more helpful...

My code followed by

**HomeActivity.java**

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

private ListOfItemAdapter listOfItemAdapter;
    private RecyclerView mainRecyclerView;
    private ArrayList<ListOfItem> mainListOfItem;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    SessionManager sessionManager;
    private String requestUrl = "my_url";
    private int pageNumber;
    private int visibleItemCount , totalCount, pastVisibleItem;
    private boolean loading=true;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.toolbar_title_layout);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        init();

    }

    private void init() {
       
          listOfItemAdapter = new ListOfItemAdapter(this);
        swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.itemSwipe);
        pageNumber =1;
        mainListOfItem = new ArrayList<>();
        sessionManager = new SessionManager(this);
        sessionManager.checkLogin();
        mainRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mainRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        mainRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        floatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
        getRequestList(requestUrl,pageNumber);

         swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                mainListOfItem.clear();
                pageNumber=1;
                loading=true;
                getRequestList(requestUrl,pageNumber);
            }
        });

        mainRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if(dy>0)
                {
                    visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
                    totalCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
                    pastVisibleItem = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                    if(loading)
                    {
                        if((visibleItemCount + pastVisibleItem) >= totalCount) {
                            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                            loading = false;
                            pageNumber += 1;
                            getRequestList(requestUrl, pageNumber);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void getRequestList(String Url, final int pNumber) {

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            try {
                JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(response);
                String success = responseObject.getString("success");
                if(success.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                    JSONObject object1 = responseObject.getJSONObject("data");
                    JSONArray jsonArray = object1.getJSONArray("data");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String itemId = data.getString("item_id");
                        String titleViewUrl = data.getString("name");
                        String imageViewUrl = data.getString("picture");
                        String descriptionViewUrl = data.getString("description");
                        String costViewUrl = data.getString("price");

                        mainListOfItem.add(new ListOfItem(itemId, imageViewUrl, titleViewUrl, descriptionViewUrl, costViewUrl));
                    }
                    if(!mainListOfItem.isEmpty())
                    {
                        loading = true;
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        StyleableToast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,"No more item available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG,R.style.failuretoastStyle).show();
                    }

                }
                listOfItemAdapter = new ListOfItemAdapter(HomeActivity.this );
                mainRecyclerView.setAdapter(listOfItemAdapter);
              listOfItemAdapter.setData(mainListOfItem);

                itemClick();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("items", "error:" + e.toString());
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String,String> params = sessionManager.getUserDetail();
            params.put("user_id", params.get(SessionManager.USER_ID));
            params.put("access_token", params.get(SessionManager.ACCESS_TOKEN));
            params.put("page",String.valueOf(pNumber));
            return params;
        }
    };
        VolleySingleton.getInstance(HomeActivity.this).addtoRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

and my singleton  followed by

**VolleySingleton.java**

```
public class VolleySingleton {
    private static VolleySingleton mInstance;
    private static Context context;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private VolleySingleton(Context context)
    {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public static synchronized VolleySingleton getInstance(Context context)
    {
        if(mInstance == null)
        {
            mInstance = new VolleySingleton(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {

        if(mRequestQueue == null)
        {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public  <T>  void addtoRequestQueue(Request <T> request)
    {
        mRequestQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is the simple solution for your problem.**

*Declare a variable of int type for current position which will hold current position* before pagination.

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

private ListOfItemAdapter listOfItemAdapter;
    private RecyclerView mainRecyclerView;
    private ArrayList<ListOfItem> mainListOfItem;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    SessionManager sessionManager;
    private String requestUrl = "my_url";
    private int pageNumber;
    private int visibleItemCount , totalCount, pastVisibleItem;
    private boolean loading=true;
    private int lastPosition=-1;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.toolbar_title_layout);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        init();

    }

    private void init() {
       
          listOfItemAdapter = new ListOfItemAdapter(this);
        swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.itemSwipe);
        pageNumber =1;
        mainListOfItem = new ArrayList<>();
        sessionManager = new SessionManager(this);
        sessionManager.checkLogin();
        mainRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mainRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        mainRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        floatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
        getRequestList(requestUrl,pageNumber);

         swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                mainListOfItem.clear();
                pageNumber=1;
                loading=true;
                getRequestList(requestUrl,pageNumber);
            }
        });

        mainRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if(dy>0)
                {
                    visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
                    totalCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
                    pastVisibleItem = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                    if(loading)
                    {
                        if((visibleItemCount + pastVisibleItem) >= totalCount) {
                            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                            loading = false;
                            pageNumber += 1;
                            getRequestList(requestUrl, pageNumber);
                            lastPosition=mainListOfItem.size();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void getRequestList(String Url, final int pNumber) {

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            try {
                JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(response);
                String success = responseObject.getString("success");
                if(success.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                    JSONObject object1 = responseObject.getJSONObject("data");
                    JSONArray jsonArray = object1.getJSONArray("data");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String itemId = data.getString("item_id");
                        String titleViewUrl = data.getString("name");
                        String imageViewUrl = data.getString("picture");
                        String descriptionViewUrl = data.getString("description");
                        String costViewUrl = data.getString("price");

                        mainListOfItem.add(new ListOfItem(itemId, imageViewUrl, titleViewUrl, descriptionViewUrl, costViewUrl));
                    }
                    if(!mainListOfItem.isEmpty())
                    {
                        loading = true;
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        StyleableToast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,"No more item available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG,R.style.failuretoastStyle).show();
                    }

                }
                listOfItemAdapter = new ListOfItemAdapter(HomeActivity.this );
                mainRecyclerView.setAdapter(listOfItemAdapter);
                listOfItemAdapter.setData(mainListOfItem);
                if(pageNumber!=1){
                mainRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(lastPosition);
                }

                itemClick();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("items", "error:" + e.toString());
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String,String> params = sessionManager.getUserDetail();
            params.put("user_id", params.get(SessionManager.USER_ID));
            params.put("access_token", params.get(SessionManager.ACCESS_TOKEN));
            params.put("page",String.valueOf(pNumber));
            return params;
        }
    };
        VolleySingleton.getInstance(HomeActivity.this).addtoRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: its working, but now when i reach the end of the first page item means, the next page items loaded by automatically scroll all the items which already loaded and stops at newly loaded item, any solution for this, becoz it looks so odd...

Comment: you should check apps like flipkart

Comment: what do you want then ?